# What is 'Automator Application Stub' on my macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, automator, monterey

After updating to macOS Monterey my macbook pro (13-inch, 2017) started running slow.

When looking at the *software->Applications in System information* I seen application name "Automator Application Stub" with Unknown "obtained from" attribute.

When I navigate to it **"/system/library/coreservices/"** and try to open it I get a message saying *"the document automator application stub.app could not be opened because it is damaged or incomplete."*

This seems suspicious because there is already an Automator application on the machine. Also, I'm not able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the system application that runs Automator applications (which have an **Automator Application Stub** executable in the bundle).

That application doesn't appear to be code-signed, which might be Apple's way of not letting *you* run it.  The system partition is also read-only, so you can't alter anything in it.